# Too many nested async methods. Is that a problem?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The following code gets a list of investments belonging to a customer from 3 different resources. The flow starts with a controller's call and follows the flow described below where all methods are declared as async and called with await operator.

I'm wondering if is there a problem making all methods as async. Is there any performance penalty? Is it a code smell or an anti-pattern?

I know there are things that must be *waited* like access url, get data from cahce, etc. But I think there are things like filling a list or sum some few values doesn't need to be async.

[image]

Below follow the code (some parts where ommited for clearness):

Controller

```
    {HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        Client client = await _mediator.Send(new RecuperarInvestimentosQuery());
        return Ok(cliente);
    }
```

QueryHandler

```
    public async Task<Client> Handle(RecoverInvestimentsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Client client;
        List<Investiment> list = await _investimentBuilder.GetInvestiments();
        client = new Cliente(request.Id, list);
        return client;
    }
```

InvestmentBuilder

```
    public async Task<List<Investiment>> GetInvestiments()
    {
        ListInvestiments builder = new ListInvestiments();
        await builder.BuildLists(_builder);
        // here I get the List<Investiment> list already fulfilled to return to the controller
        return list;
    }
```

BuildLists

```
    public async Task BuildLists(IBuilder builder)
    {
        Task[] tasks = new Task[] {
            builder.GetFundsAsync(),   //****
            builder.ObterTesouro(),
            builder.ObterRendaFixa()
        };
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

Funds, Bonds and Fixed Income Services (***all 3 methods are equal, only its name vary, so I just put one of them for the sake of saving space)

```
    public async Task GetFundsAsync()
    {
        var listOfFunds = await _FundsService.RecoverFundsAsync();
        // listOfFunds will get all items from all types of investments
    }
```

Recover Funds, Bonds and Fixed Incomes methods are equals too, again I just put one of them

```
    public async Task<List<Funds>> RecoverFundsAsync()
    {
        var returnCache = await _clientCache.GetValueAsync("fundsService");
        // if not in cache, so go get from url
        if (returnCache == null)
        {
            string url = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Urls:Funds");
            var response = await _clienteHttp.ObterDadosAsync(url);
            if (response != null)
            {
                string funds = JObject.Parse(response).SelectToken("funds").ToString();
                await _clienteCache.SetValueAsync("fundService", funds);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Funds>>(fundos);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Funds>>(returnCache);
    }
```

HTTP Client

```
    public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string Url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(Url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Cache Client

```
    public async Task<string> GetValueAsync(string key)
    {
        IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
        RedisValue value = await cache.StringGetAsync(key);
        if (value.HasValue)
            return value.ToString();
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Could someone give a thought about that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for me, there's not so many `async` methods. Leave it if you're ok with performance. I see one huge possible overhead: you're creating new `HttpClient` for each request either through factory. Consider reusing single one in case you have same connection settings for each request. Simply create one static instance and use it along the entire app life, you'll gain the performance boost related to http requests query time then.

Comment: Also you may make http faster with `client.GetAsync(Url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)`. It will pass to http success status check direclty after headers are received instead of reading the whole response. And `HttpResponseMessage` (`var response`) is `IDisposable`, implement `using` for it.

Comment: In case you're need a better performance in code overloaded with `Task`, learn something about [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: I think, it's better to ask this question on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The only problem I can see is the inconsistency of the `Async` suffix. Some times it is there, sometimes it's not. I would suggest to add it in all async methods, to be in par with the official [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, following official guidelines for applications which heavily using databases and web services, will make almost all method names with Async suffix ;)

Comment: @Fabio this is a valid argument. Even in this case I think that there is some value in following the guidelines though. Of course these are just recommendations, and personal judgement per case is applicable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the original code is in Portuguese, I had to translate to English for better understanding. Sorry I made some mispelling while translating, but yes, I do follow the guidelines and use Async as suffix for async methods. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okay for me. You are using `async` and `await` just for `I/O` and web access operations, and it perfectly fits for [`async` and `await` purposes:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

- For I/O-bound code, you await an operation that returns a Task or Task inside of an async method.
- For CPU-bound code, you await an operation that is started on a background thread with the Task.Run method.

Once you've used `async` and `await`, then all pieces of your code tends to become asynchronous too. This fact is described greatly in the  MSDN article - [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming):

> Asynchronous code reminds me of the story of a fellow who mentioned
>   that the world was suspended in space and was immediately challenged
>   by an elderly lady claiming that the world rested on the back of a
>   giant turtle. When the man enquired what the turtle was standing on,
>   the lady replied, “You’re very clever, young man, but it’s turtles all
>   the way down!” As you convert synchronous code to asynchronous code,
>   you’ll find that it works best if asynchronous code calls and is
>   called by other asynchronous code—all the way down (or “up,” if you
>   prefer). Others have also noticed the spreading behavior of
>   asynchronous programming and have called it “contagious” or compared
>   it to a zombie virus. Whether turtles or zombies, it’s definitely true
>   that asynchronous code tends to drive surrounding code to also be
>   asynchronous. This behavior is inherent in all types of asynchronous
>   programming, not just the new async/await keywords.